# Speech Recognition in Flash

Tags: flash, speech-recognition

I am trying to develop a module for voice recognition that could be integrated with a pre-existing flash website. I don't need the full speech recognition functionality, but a limited set of it (only specific commands like next, go etc). I looked at some functionality available like [speechapi](http://www.speechapi.com/live-demos/parrot.html). I am a newbie to flash and never have tried flash much. I did try to do a bit of flash training by myself since i got into this project. So anyway, if I have to go ahead, will I have to do this in Actionscript? Or is there some other language that i can use? if indeed i have to use actionscript, could you please recommend a good tutorial to learn it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the speechapi documentation, it doesn't look like there's an API for working directly in ActionScript. However, the basic JavaScript API would appear to meet your requirements for the speech recognition side of things.

If you can get a JavaScript implementation of speechapi functioning as required, you should find it reasonably simple to communicate with your pre-existing Flash site using [ExternalInterface](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html) (the preferred method of communication between JavaScript and ActionScript, and vice versa).

In theory, you shouldn't need to write much ActionScript at all.